Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library with Eclipse latest version and the installer
After a recent update, I'm now not able to run Eclipse on Windows and am getting the following error:
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
An error has occurred. See the log file
F:\e\2024-09\configuration\1726759018149.log.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------


!SESSION 2024-09-19 20:46:57.918 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.33.0.20240905-0613
java.version=21.0.4
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean

!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-09-19 20:48:22.360
!MESSAGE Activated before the state location was initialized. Retry after the state location is initialized.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-09-19 20:48:28.268
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    F:\e\2024-09\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\800\0\.cp\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path: F:\e\2024-09;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;.
    no swt in java.library.path: F:\e\2024-09;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\windows\system32;.
    C:\Users\Username\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Username\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Username\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll
    C:\Users\Username\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.STARTUPINFO.<clinit>(STARTUPINFO.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)

I have deleted the C:\Users\User\.swt folder also but still no luck.
Also don't know how to install the latest SWT on windows via the following page:
https://www.eclipse.org/swt/
What can I do to fix this issue so that I can load Eclipse IDE 2024-09 without any issues?


When a new Eclipse version is released, I simply delete the existing "eclipse" folder on my computer, download the appropriate ZIP from eclipse.org and simply unpack it. How do you "update"?

Did that also but this SWT error is not going away.
I tried using their Eclipse Installer by Oomph that also to my surprise fails to start up and gives the same SWT library error.

Also, first time I run Eclipse after installing a new release, I use -clean as in: eclipse.exe -clean.

Tried that as well but same old SWT error.

Please show the error message you get when you unzip eclipse-jee-2024-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip into an empty folder and run it with a fresh workspace.

What is this F: drive? Do you have execute permissions there?

Yes @nitind I do have permissions on F:
@howlger: I downloaded the zip, extracted all the files, ran eclipse.exe -clean command and the same SWT error. What should I do?

UPDATE: If I use eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip and installed it w/o any other changes - it works!
So is this a known bug issue with 2024-09-R-win32-x86_64?

No, it's not a known bug. Eclipse 2024-09 works fine for me on Windows 11. According to your error log in your questions you use Java 23 from Oracle installed on your system. But the ZIP includes its own Java. So please show the log file from the unzipped Eclipse  that has been created in the configuration folder after extracting the ZIP file into an empty folder (it is important that the folder is empty before you extracted the ZIP file). The error is shown before the workspace selection dialog immediately after starting Eclipse, right?

@howlger: Again extracted everything from eclipse-jee-2024-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip, tried to execute eclipse using command eclipse.exe -clean and got the same Error dialog box with error An error has occurred. See the log file F:\e\2024-09\configuration\1726759018149.log. and yes it appears immediately after starting Eclipse and I don't see any workspace selection option/dialog.

Which release of Windows are you on, Rashy?

If you are using a Windows version other than 10 or 11, see https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/1252

@nitind It's Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - Is it not supported?

Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter) is not officially supported by Eclipse 2024-09 (4.33).
According to the project plan of the Eclipse project, Eclipse 2024-09 (4.33) is tested and validated on Windows with Windows 10 and 11 only.
For details see Eclipse platform SWT issue #1252.

And see https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/1500
